# how to fix A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m getting the "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled"

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
const {name} = user;

const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    setUser((prevState) => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        };
    });
};
```

when I render the person

```
<input
    name="name"
    value={name}
    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
/>
```

name is undefined so that´s probably why is triggering the warning. but can I just create the name inside user?

I´m getting the expected outcome just want to get rid of the warning

if I do console.log(user) I see the name just fine.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure `value` is never undefined:

```
<input
    name="name"
    value={name || ''}
    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: i´m too tired. that was pretty obvious hehe thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just initialise input with empty string when undefined. Warning will go away.

```js
<input
    name="name"
    value={name || ""}
    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
/>
```